# Java 8 parallel stream or method execution

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

I have a class that constructs several foo objects. The problem right now is that the class iterates one by one down a list and builds them. I want to see if there's a way to make all of the building happen in parallel. Here's the class in question:

```
public List<Foo> create() {}
    List<Class> fooTypes = Arrays.asList(
                    Foo1.class,
                    Foo2.class,
                    Foo3.class,
                    Foo4.class,
                    Foo5.class,
                    Foo6.class
            );

    List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Class<? extends Foo> fooType : fooTypes) {
        Optional<Foo> foo = findByType(fooType);
        if(foo.isPresent()) {
            foos.add(foo.get());
        }
    }
    return foos;
}

private Optional<Foo> findByType(Class<? extends Foo> fooClass) {
    if(fooClass.isAssignableFrom(Foo1.class)) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(foo1());
    }
    if(fooClass.isAssignableFrom(Foo2.class)) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(foo2());
    }
    if(fooClass.isAssignableFrom(Foo3.class)) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(foo3());
    }
    if(fooClass.isAssignableFrom(Foo4.class)) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(foo4());
    }
    if(fooClass.isAssignableFrom(Foo5.class)) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(foo5());
    }
    if(fooClass.isAssignableFrom(Foo6.class)) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(foo6());
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}

private Alert foo1() {
    return new Foo1Builder().build();
}
private Alert foo2() {
    return new Foo2Builder().build();
}
private Alert foo3() {
    return new Foo3Builder().build();
}
private Alert foo4() {
    return new Foo4Builder().build();
}
private Alert foo5() {
    return new Foo5Builder().build();
}
private Alert foo6() {
    return new Foo6Builder().build();
}
```

Is there a way to convert the `foreach` loop into a java 8 parallel stream? If not, is going the executor route outlined [here](http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/07/java8-concurrency-tutorial-thread-executor-examples/) the correct way to go? I tried something like this to implement parallel streams but something is just not correct:

```
foos = fooTypes
        .parallelStream()
        .filter(a -> findByType(a).isPresent())
        .map(Optional::get)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Your `filter` is incorrect: `map` first, then filter on `isPresent`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A parallel stream will be much less efficient than a sequential stream for such a small number of elements. It's overkill.

But you can use a Stream, indeed:

```
foos = fooTypes
        .stream()
        .map(this::findByType)
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .map(Optional::get)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

That said, I really don't know what you gain by iterating on the classes to find which method to call on each class. Why not just use

```
return Arrays.asList(new Foo1Builder().build(),
                     new Foo2Builder().build(),
                     ...);
```

It seems much less convoluted to me.

Comment: i got an error when i tried this. it said `Bad return type in method reference: cannot convert Optional<Foo> to R`

Comment: Your list of classes should be of type `List<Class<? extends Foo>>`.

Comment: i tried changing the list from `List<Class>` to `List<Class<? extends Foo>>` and same error. Additionally, if I want to pass in other arguments into `findByType` how could I do that?

Comment: It compiles fine here, with that complete minimal self-contained example: https://gist.github.com/jnizet/d4192cc0ce33847969af547b4d37dd36. Not sure why it doesn't at your side. Try posting a complete minimal self-contained example reproducing your compilation error.

Comment: To pass another argument to findByType, use a lambda rather than a method reference: `map(clazz -> findByType(clazz, 1, 2, 3))`

Comment: perfect, that did it for me! I timed the execution and the stream cut my time by half